# How to acknowledge Math Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, citation

In my research problem,  I have got help from Math Stack Exchange. So in my paper, I want to acknowledge MSE. Hence if I write in the Acknowledgement 
"I want to acknowledge Math Stack Exchange Community for many helpful discussions.", is it ok?

Comment: You should read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4259/do-i-cite-mathstackexchange-in-my-paper and the linked questions.